# How to call only specific functions that have an annotation or tag

Tags: go, annotations

Is there a way to add a tag or annotate some methods so that whenever an event arises all the methods with this tag or annotation get invoked?

How to achieve this in Go?

Comment: No. There are no annotations or tags on functions in Go.

Comment: If you explain your larger goal, there's almost certainly a way to achieve it, though. This looks like an XY Problem.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do some kind of AOP maybe? That's not supported in Go, but maybe you can provide some detail on what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to run a go-client for Kubernetes, whenever a k8 service gets created I want to call n number of different sub-routines that perform different actions.

Comment: Do not edit the title to add tags. Tag (i.e. "In Go,") should [_not_ be in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/165502).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, no there are no annotations or tags on functions in Go.

However, it is more than possible to use a `map` (or `slice`) and a register function to keep records of other `func`s (or `interface`s). You just need to manually call that register `func` (usually in `init()` of that package).

For example,

```
package events

var eventFuncs = make(map[string]func())
func Register(event string, f func()) {
    eventFuncs[event] = append(eventFuncs[event],f)
}

func Get(event string) []func() {
    return eventFuncs[event]
}
```

And using the package to register:

```
package xy

import (
    "fmt"

    "some.url/events"
)

func Call() {
    fmt.Println("Ha!")
}
func init() {
    events.Register("x",Call)
}
```

And then call the `func`s elsewhere:

```
package main

import (
    "some.url/events"
)

func main() {
    for _,f := range pkg.GetEvent("x") { f() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add tag to the struct of the first parameter of the function.
Then you can use reflect to read the tag to do whatever you want.
For example I just want to add a menu to my admin website to this url `/ListToTablePage` this handler stand for with the menu `ListToTable`

```
func (h web_t) ListToTablePage(req struct{
    _ struct{} `menu:"ListToTable"`
}){
}
...
```